# Excel неправильный поиск в строке python

Tags: python, pandas, excel

У меня в файле значение name находится в строке 10 но почему-то код определяет как 8

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Cat\AppData\Roaming\ACode\first project\basedata.xlsx')


filtered_rows = df[df.applymap(lambda x: 'name' in str(x).lower()).any(axis=1)]

for index in filtered_rows.index:
    okey = index
    values_row_8 = filtered_rows.iloc[okey].tolist()
    print(f"Значения в строке 8: {values_row_8}")
```

Comment: вы же сами пишите в коде про 8-ю строку. и потом, откуда нам знать, в какой строке у вас искомое значение в файле?

Answer (score 0):

Можно предположить (не видя источника данных), что 10 строка становится 8-й по двум причинам.
Первая причина - первая строка становится заголовком фрейма, т.к. в методе [pd.read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) параметр `header` по умолчанию равен 0, т.е. значения первой (или нулевой с точки зрения pandas) строки используются как метки для столбцов фрейма.
Вторая причина - из-за разницы в нумерации строк. В Excel она начинается с 1, а во фрейме с 0.
Каждая из причин "сдвигает" нумерацию строк на 1, поэтому 10 - 2 = 8